# Is there a way using SQL to insert duplicate rows into Table A depending upon the results of a number column in Table B?

Tags: sql, t-sql, duplicates

I am using TSQL on SQL Server and have bumped into a challenge...

I am querying the data out of TableA and then inserting it into TableB. See my stored procedure code below for more info.

However as an added layer of complexity one of the Columns in TableA holds a numeric number (It can be any number from 0 to 50) and depending upon this number I have to make 'n' number of Duplicates for that specific row. (for example in TableA we have a column called TableA.RepeatNumber and this will dictate how many duplicate rows I need to create of this row in TableB. Its worth noting that some of the rows won't need any duplicates as they will have a value of 0 in TableA.RepeatNumber)

(This stored procedure below works fine to insert single rows into TableB.)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_rows]

    @IDCode     As NVarChar(20),
    @UserName   As NVarChar(20)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

Insert INTO TableB (Status, Number, Date, Time, User)
    SELECT Status, Number, date, Time, User, 
      FROM TableA where Status = 1 AND RepeatNumber > 0 AND Code = @IDCode AND User = @UserName

END
```

Any pointers on where I should look to find a solution to this problem (if it exists would be greatly appreciated.)

Best wishes

Dick

Comment: You say a `RepeatNumber` of `0` means no 'duplicates' but your code completely filters them out.  Do you want one row inserted for a `RepeatNumber` of `0` or none?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with a as (
      select a.Status, a.Number, a.date, a.Time, a.User, a.RepeatNumber, 1 as seqnum
      from tablea a
      where Status = 1 and RepeatNumber > 0 and Code = @IDCode and User = @UserName
      union all
      select Status, Number, date, Time, User, RepeatNumber, seqnum + 1
      from a
      where seqnum < RepeatNumber
     )
insert INTO TableB (Status, Number, Date, Time, User)
    select Status, Number, date, Time, User 
    from a;
```

You only need up to 50 duplicates, so you don't have to worry about maximum recursion.

A numbers table can also be used for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I will dig into this.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this using a numbers table and avoiding recursion which may have a performance penalty, you can do the following (if you already have an actual numbers table in your database you can just `join` to that and avoid the `cte`):

```
declare @TableA table(Status nvarchar(10),RepeatNumber int,[date] date,Time time,[User] nvarchar(10));
insert into @TableA values('Status 0',0,'20190101','00:00:00','User 0'),('Status 1',1,'20190101','01:01:01','User 1'),('Status 2',2,'20190102','02:02:02','User 2'),('Status 3',3,'20190103','03:03:03','User 3');

with t(t)as(select t from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))as t(t))
    ,n(n)as(select top 50 row_number()over(order by(select null)) from t,t t2)
select Status
      ,RepeatNumber
      ,[date]
      ,Time
      ,[User]
      ,n.n
from @TableA as a
    join n
        on a.RepeatNumber >= n.n
where RepeatNumber > 0
order by a.Status
        ,n.n;
```

## Output

```
+----------+--------------+------------+------------------+--------+---+
|  Status  | RepeatNumber |    date    |       Time       |  User  | n |
+----------+--------------+------------+------------------+--------+---+
| Status 1 |            1 | 2019-01-01 | 01:01:01.0000000 | User 1 | 1 |
| Status 2 |            2 | 2019-01-02 | 02:02:02.0000000 | User 2 | 1 |
| Status 2 |            2 | 2019-01-02 | 02:02:02.0000000 | User 2 | 2 |
| Status 3 |            3 | 2019-01-03 | 03:03:03.0000000 | User 3 | 1 |
| Status 3 |            3 | 2019-01-03 | 03:03:03.0000000 | User 3 | 2 |
| Status 3 |            3 | 2019-01-03 | 03:03:03.0000000 | User 3 | 3 |
+----------+--------------+------------+------------------+--------+---+
```

Comment: Looks promising Dave, 1st step, create a numbers table, thank you for your pointers.